# failed to run custom build command for `librocksdb-sys v6.20.3`

Tags: build, rocks-db

My build was working last week now I can't build rocksdb for some reason.

I made sure that I went though the [install steps](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/getting-started/installation/) again in case I was missing something.

Here's the rest of the out:

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `librocksdb-sys v6.20.3`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/christian/something/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-da8801d786dd32a1/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=rocksdb/
  TARGET = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
  OPT_LEVEL = Some("3")
  HOST = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
  CXX_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  CXX_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  HOST_CXX = None
  CXX = None
  CXXFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  CXXFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  HOST_CXXFLAGS = None
  CXXFLAGS = None
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  DEBUG = Some("false")
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,llvm14-builtins-abi,sse,sse2")
  CXX_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  CXX_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  HOST_CXX = None
  CXX = None
  CXXFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  CXXFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  HOST_CXXFLAGS = None
  CXXFLAGS = None
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,llvm14-builtins-abi,sse,sse2")
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++11" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-msse2" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-o" "/home/christian/something/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-53fb9acd9310b761/out/rocksdb/db/blob/blob_file_builder.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/blob/blob_file_builder.cc"
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++11" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-msse2" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-o" "/home/christian/something/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-53fb9acd9310b761/out/rocksdb/db/arena_wrapped_db_iter.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/arena_wrapped_db_iter.cc"
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++11" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-msse2" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-o" "/home/christian/something/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-53fb9acd9310b761/out/rocksdb/cache/cache.o" "-c" "rocksdb/cache/cache.cc"
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++11" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-msse2" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-o" "/home/christian/something/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-53fb9acd9310b761/out/rocksdb/db/blob/blob_file_cache.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/blob/blob_file_cache.cc"
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++11" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-msse2" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-o" "/home/christian/something/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-53fb9acd9310b761/out/rocksdb/cache/sharded_cache.o" "-c" "rocksdb/cache/sharded_cache.cc"
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++11" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-msse2" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-o" "/home/christian/something/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-53fb9acd9310b761/out/rocksdb/cache/lru_cache.o" "-c" "rocksdb/cache/lru_cache.cc"
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++11" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-msse2" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-o" "/home/christian/something/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-53fb9acd9310b761/out/rocksdb/cache/clock_cache.o" "-c" "rocksdb/cache/clock_cache.cc"
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++11" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-msse2" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-o" "/home/christian/something/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-53fb9acd9310b761/out/rocksdb/db/blob/blob_file_addition.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/blob/blob_file_addition.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++11" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-msse2" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-o" "/home/christian/something/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-53fb9acd9310b761/out/rocksdb/db/blob/blob_file_garbage.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/blob/blob_file_garbage.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++11" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-msse2" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-o" "/home/christian/something/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-53fb9acd9310b761/out/rocksdb/db/blob/blob_file_meta.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/blob/blob_file_meta.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++11" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-msse2" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-o" "/home/christian/something/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-53fb9acd9310b761/out/rocksdb/db/blob/blob_file_reader.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/blob/blob_file_reader.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++11" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-msse2" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-o" "/home/christian/something/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-53fb9acd9310b761/out/rocksdb/db/blob/blob_log_format.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/blob/blob_log_format.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++11" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-msse2" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-o" "/home/christian/something/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-53fb9acd9310b761/out/rocksdb/db/blob/blob_log_sequential_reader.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/blob/blob_log_sequential_reader.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++11" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-msse2" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-o" "/home/christian/something/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-53fb9acd9310b761/out/rocksdb/db/blob/blob_log_writer.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/blob/blob_log_writer.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++11" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-msse2" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-o" "/home/christian/something/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-53fb9acd9310b761/out/rocksdb/db/builder.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/builder.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++11" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-msse2" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-o" "/home/christian/something/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-53fb9acd9310b761/out/rocksdb/db/c.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/c.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++11" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-msse2" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-o" "/home/christian/something/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-53fb9acd9310b761/out/rocksdb/db/column_family.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/column_family.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++11" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-msse2" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-o" "/home/christian/something/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-53fb9acd9310b761/out/rocksdb/db/compaction/compaction.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/compaction/compaction.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++11" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-msse2" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-o" "/home/christian/something/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-53fb9acd9310b761/out/rocksdb/db/compaction/compaction_iterator.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/compaction/compaction_iterator.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++11" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-msse2" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-o" "/home/christian/something/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-53fb9acd9310b761/out/rocksdb/db/compaction/compaction_job.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/compaction/compaction_job.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++11" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-msse2" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-o" "/home/christian/something/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-53fb9acd9310b761/out/rocksdb/db/compaction/compaction_picker.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/compaction/compaction_picker.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++11" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-msse2" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-o" "/home/christian/something/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-53fb9acd9310b761/out/rocksdb/db/compaction/compaction_picker_fifo.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/compaction/compaction_picker_fifo.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++11" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-msse2" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-o" "/home/christian/something/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-53fb9acd9310b761/out/rocksdb/db/compaction/compaction_picker_level.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/compaction/compaction_picker_level.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++11" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-msse2" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-o" "/home/christian/something/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-53fb9acd9310b761/out/rocksdb/db/compaction/compaction_picker_universal.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/compaction/compaction_picker_universal.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++11" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-msse2" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-o" "/home/christian/something/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-53fb9acd9310b761/out/rocksdb/db/compaction/sst_partitioner.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/compaction/sst_partitioner.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++11" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-msse2" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-o" "/home/christian/something/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-53fb9acd9310b761/out/rocksdb/db/convenience.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/convenience.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++11" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-msse2" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-o" "/home/christian/something/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-53fb9acd9310b761/out/rocksdb/db/db_filesnapshot.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/db_filesnapshot.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++11" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-msse2" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-o" "/home/christian/something/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-53fb9acd9310b761/out/rocksdb/db/db_impl/compacted_db_impl.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/db_impl/compacted_db_impl.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++11" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-msse2" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-o" "/home/christian/something/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-53fb9acd9310b761/out/rocksdb/db/db_impl/db_impl.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/db_impl/db_impl.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++11" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-msse2" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-o" "/home/christian/something/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-53fb9acd9310b761/out/rocksdb/db/db_impl/db_impl_compaction_flush.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/db_impl/db_impl_compaction_flush.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++11" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-msse2" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-o" "/home/christian/something/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-53fb9acd9310b761/out/rocksdb/db/db_impl/db_impl_debug.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/db_impl/db_impl_debug.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++11" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-msse2" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-o" "/home/christian/something/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-53fb9acd9310b761/out/rocksdb/db/db_impl/db_impl_experimental.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/db_impl/db_impl_experimental.cc"
  cargo:warning=c++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
  cargo:warning=Please submit a full bug report,
  cargo:warning=with preprocessed source if appropriate.
  cargo:warning=See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs> for instructions.
  exit status: 4
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++11" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-msse2" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-o" "/home/christian/something/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-53fb9acd9310b761/out/rocksdb/db/db_impl/db_impl_files.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/db_impl/db_impl_files.cc"
  exit status: 0
  exit status: 0
  exit status: 0
  exit status: 0
  exit status: 0
  exit status: 0
  exit status: 0
  exit status: 0

  --- stderr


  error occurred: Command "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++11" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-msse2" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-o" "/home/christian/something/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-53fb9acd9310b761/out/rocksdb/db/compaction/compaction_job.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/compaction/compaction_job.cc" with args "c++" did not execute successfully (status code exit status: 4).
```

When I run rustup show:

```
rustup show                                                                                     git:master*
Default host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
rustup home:  /home/christian/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

wasm32-unknown-unknown
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

active toolchain
----------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.60.0 (7737e0b5c 2022-04-04)
```

Comment: It reports "c++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)", which is a GCC fault. "Just retry it" normally works.

Comment: I restarted my computer and it compiled.

Comment: There is an open issue already:
https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/issues/338

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following resolved issue may answer you question. Cheers! https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/issues/338#issuecomment-1118007694

NB: Probably same issue as: [question](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2655/not-able-to-build-librocksdb-sys-library-for-substrate-node-template).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a bit more pure rust then you can enable the feature `with-parity-db` and it won't use rocksdb.

Alternatively if you look in `shell.nix` you can see we set up these env vars:

```
  RUST_SRC_PATH = "${rust-nightly}/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src";
  LIBCLANG_PATH = "${llvmPackages.libclang.lib}/lib";
  PROTOC = "${protobuf}/bin/protoc";
  ROCKSDB_LIB_DIR = "${rocksdb}/lib";
```

Assuming you've installed rocksdb then `ROCKSDB_LIB_DIR` is probably what your missing. (I'm on nixos so everything works for me)

Comment: I already have all those env variables. 
If I were to try the parity db where exactly do I enable it? In the runtime/Cargo.toml?

Comment: just as you build cumulus or polkadot: `cargo build --features with-parity-db`