# Not able to build librocksdb-sys library for substrate-node-template

Tags: substrate-node-template, rocks-db

Getting this error while building substrate-node-template,
Command uses: cargo build --release

error: failed to run custom build command for `librocksdb-sys v0.6.1+6.28.2`

MacBook Air 2017, MacOS Monterey 12.3.1, Processor:  1.8 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5,Memory: 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3

Answer (score 5):

I think this is solved by installing LLVM : https://releases.llvm.org/download.html.
when you open this link you will find macOs option inside LLVM 11.0.0
Just install it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following resolved issue may answer you question. Cheers!
https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/issues/338#issuecomment-1118007694